# Edit registry for current user through scheduled task

Tags: windows, perl, registry, scheduled-tasks

I've written a Perl script that allows the modification of the current user's wallpaper on Windows 7 using Strawberry Perl. It works in 3 steps:

1. use of Perl `Image::Magick` module to generate a composite picture;
2. activation of the composite picture as current wallpaper using Perl `Win32::API` module;
3. edition of 2 registry keys (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/Desktop//TileWallpaper` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/Desktop//WallpaperStyle`) using Perl `Win32::TieRegistry` module to adapt to multi-monitors setup.

The given script works:

- when run from CLI;
- when set as a scheduled task, option `Run only if a user is logged on` (the syntax being `perl` w/ arguments `-I<path/to/lib> <outfile>`).

But the script does not work when run as a scheduled task, option `Run whether the user is logged on or not` (AFAICS, only the step #1 works).

I thought that the issue was coming from the fact that the scheduled task in run by a different user than the one set up (I think it is named `system`) and therefore, the registry key is no longer `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.

So I tried editing the registry keys in `HKEY_USER/<SID>/Control Panel/Desktop` but the values are not the same as the one in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/Desktop`.

I also tried wrapping the Perl executable and its arguments in a batch file and call it directly in a scheduled task but AFAICS only the first step works.

I tried logging the output of the script but there is no useful output (apart from the expected STDOUT).

Do you see any reason why the registry edits are not working from a scheduled task in `Run whether the user is logged on or not` mode?

Comment: I tested editing the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/Desktop//Wallpaper` directly through a scheduled task in `Run whether the user is logged on or not` mode and it worked. So I guess the issue is w/ finding which registry key to edit for setting a wallpaper...

Comment: I narrowed down the issue to triggering a registry refresh after editing it. For information, I used some code based on the following link : http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=181191

Comment: All my attempts to trigger a registry refresh from the Win32 API from a scheduled task in `Run whether the user is logged on or not` mode proved either fruitless or non-reliable. I circumvented the issue by running the Perl code in a batch file w/ the following syntax :

`start /min <path/to/batch/file>`

It stills pops up a `taskeng.exe` DOS prompt but it is better than nothing.

Comment: I found a code snippet from Strawberry Perl used to trigger a refresh but it does not work on Windows 7 x64 w/ Strawberry Perl x86 v5.16.3001.

Source : https://github.com/StrawberryPerl/Perl-Dist-Strawberry/blob/master/share/extra-files/update_env.pl.bat#L119